# Are the details given about Grindelwald on the Harry Potter Wiki accurate?

Tags: harry-potter, canon, gellert-grindelwald

I was amazed by the details about Grindelwald on the [*Harry Potter* Wikia.](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gellert_Grindelwald)

I have only seen the movies of *Harry Potter* and there are very few details in them.

So my question is thus:

**Are all of these details given in books or is there any other source?**

Comment: It seems as if you are asking two questions here: 1) Are all the details on the wiki page given in the books, and 2) should you read the books after the movie. You should probably ask them separately, or this question might be considered “too broad.”

Comment: Both are yes and no answers how can they be broad?

Comment: @Kesh - Asking two separate questions in the same post is considered "too broad".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiki page as usual is a mixture of canon sources, non-canon sources and people's imagination.

If you are interested in learning about Grindelwald, your best bet would be to read *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*. This is currently the biggest source of information about Grindelwald.

Note that Grindelwald was also briefly mentioned in the first book, in a few of the  interviews, and in a recently discovered letter to a fan from 2008. However, none of those really go into his back story.

- Books

  - *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* (first mention)
  - *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* (main source of information, including backstory)
- Interviews

  - [Jones, Owen. One-on-one interview with J.K. Rowling](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-edinburgh-jones-official.html) (the Hitler parallel was intentional)
  - [The Leaky Cauldron and Mugglenet interview Joanne Kathleen Rowling: Part Three](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-tlc_mugglenet-anelli-3.htm) (pronounced "Grindelvald")
  - [PotterCast Interviews J.K. Rowling, part one](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1217-pottercast-anelli.html)
- Other

  - [2008 letter to a fan](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CucMTukWcAA01pv.jpg:large)

The upcoming five Fantastic Beasts screenplays that Rowling is writing will likely give us even more information.